# How to check the independence of functions of some variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

Given some functions $f(x,y,z),\  g(x,y,z),\, $ and $h(x,y,z)$, can I check their independence by the following criterion?

> $f,g$ and $h$ are independent if their gradients (which now becomes a vector with the bases $\hat{x},\hat{y},\hat{z}$) are linearly independent.

So, now the problem becomes that of linear algebra.

Is the above line of action correct? If the above statement is correct, please also refer me to a proof.

Comment: Linear independence of $\nabla f, \nabla g, \nabla h$ will always imply that $f, g, h$ are linearly independent (as $\nabla$ is a linear function). However, the converse is not so clear. Are you wanting to know if this converse is true, or are you looking for other ways to solve problems like these?

Comment: @TheoBendit I modified the question a bit. I want the proof of the statement in my question (linear independence of gradients of functions implies independence of functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments, if $\nabla f, \nabla g, \nabla h$ are linearly independent, then so are $f, g, h$. In particular, if we have scalars, $a, b, c$ such that
$$af + bg + ch = 0$$
as functions, then taking $\nabla$ of both sides yields
$$a \nabla f + b \nabla g + c \nabla h = \nabla 0 = 0.$$
If $\nabla f, \nabla g, \nabla h$ are linearly independent, then $a = b = c = 0$, and hence $f, g, h$ are linearly independent.

The question is, does the converse hold? If $f, g, h$ are linearly independent, is the same true for $\nabla f, \nabla g, \nabla h$? Unfortunately, the converse doesn't hold in general. I've adapted the corresponding counterexample that Peano provided for Wronskians. Let:
\begin{align*}
f(x, y, z) &= x^2y^2z^2 \\
g(x, y, z) &= x^2y^2z|z| \\
h(x, y, z) &= x^2yz|yz|.
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
\nabla f(x, y, z) &= (2xy^2z^2, 2x^2yz^2, 2x^2y^2z) \\
\nabla g(x, y, z) &= (2xy^2z|z|, 2x^2yz|z|, 2x^2y^2|z|) \\
\nabla h(x, y, z) &= (2xyz|yz|, 2x^2z|yz|, 2x^2y|yz|).
\end{align*}
Putting these as columns in a matrix,
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 2xy^2z^2 & 2xy^2z|z| & 2xyz|yz| \\ 2x^2yz^2 & 2x^2yz|z| & 2x^2z|yz| \\ 2x^2y^2z & 2x^2y^2|z| & 2x^2y|yz| \end{bmatrix}.$$
Using the multilinearity of the determinant (as a function of column vectors), we can pull some factors out of the determinant:
$$\det A = (2xyz) \cdot (2xy|z|) \cdot (2x|yz|) \cdot \det \begin{bmatrix} yz & yz & yz \\ xz & xz & xz \\ xy & xy & xy \end{bmatrix} = 0.$$
However, I claim that $f, g, h$ are linearly independent. Suppose that $a, b, c$ exist such that
$$af + bg + ch = 0$$
which is to say, for all $x, y, z \in \Bbb{R}$,
$$ax^2 y^2 z^2 + b x^2 y^2 z |z| + c x^2 yz |yz| = 0.$$
For example, if $(x, y, z) = (1, 1, 1)$,
$$a + b + c = 0.$$
Another example: if $(x, y, z) = (1, 1, -1)$, then
$$a - b - c = 0.$$
Similarly, if $(x, y, z) = (1, -1, -1)$, then
$$a - b + c = 0.$$
The only possible values for $a, b, c$ is $a = b = c = 0$, hence $f, g, h$ are linearly independent, completing the counterexample.

Comment: I should point out, as I didn't make this clear in my example, the given $\nabla f, \nabla g, \nabla h$ are actually linearly independent, but when evaluated at any given $(x, y, z)$, they form linearly dependent vectors in $\Bbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Can you please share the name of the book and full name of the author you cited above (Peano)? Thanks!

Comment: It's been over a year, but if I remember correctly, I got this information about Peano from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian#The_Wronskian_and_linear_independence), which points to Peano's paper in 1889.